# Exclude elements from a list of named numbers based on entries within a character list using purrr

Tags: r, purrr

My data has 1,000 entries and here is the `str` of the first 2 elements:

```
    > str(my_boots[1:2])
List of 2
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ result  : Named num [1:10] 0.118 0.948 4.317 1.226 1.028 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "pvi2" "freqchal" "sexexp" ...
  ..$ output  : chr "list()"
  ..$ warnings: chr(0) 
  ..$ messages: chr(0) 
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ result  : Named num [1:10] 0.202 0.995 2.512 1.057 0.5 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "(Intercept)" "pvi2" "freqchal" "sexexp" ...
  ..$ output  : chr "list()"
  ..$ warnings: chr(0) 
  ..$ messages: chr(0)
```

The fields of interest are `$result` and `$warnings`; I want to return a tibble with the columns based on the names within the named list `result` where `warning == ""` (where no warning).

I'm new to `purrr` but I was able to get most of the way there using `map_dfr(my_boots[1:2],"result")` - this returns a tibble with the column names from the named numbers list but I would like to only return the ones where the entry under `warnings` is blank.

I wasn't sure how to create this structure manually but was able to create a single element of my_boots:

```
test <- list(
  list("warnings" = c("blah")), 
  list("result" = c("alpha" = 1.1, "beta" = 2.1, "theta" =3.1, "blah" = 4.1))
)
```

Also: I'm using the `tidyverse` - thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for `purrr::keep`? You can share part of your data via `dput()` and paste the output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with some dummy data.

```
library(tidyverse)

l <- list(
  list(
    result = 1:10,
    warnings = character(0)
  ),
  list(
    result = 2:20,
    warnings = "warn"
  ),
  list(
    result = 3:30,
    warnings = character(0)
  ),
  list(
    result = 4:40,
    warnings = "warn"
  )
)
```

Use `keep` to keep only elements without warnings. `map("result")` pulls the `result` element out of each list.

```
l %>%
  keep(~is_empty(.$warnings)) %>%
  map("result")
#> [[1]]
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
#> [22] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```